# LoadError in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm teaching myself ruby and have worked with Testfirst.org's curriculum, so I've used rspec before, but in a different directory. Now I'm I'm working through the following guide: http://guides.railsgirls.com/testing-rspec/

...at the first "rspec spec/lib/idea_spec.rb" I get:

```
Amys-MacBook-Air:railsgirls alightholder$ rspec spec/lib/idea_spec.rb
/Users/alightholder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rspec-core-3.1.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `load': cannot load such file -- /Users/alightholder/Ruby/railsgirls_stuff/railsgirls/spec/lib/idea_spec.rb (LoadError)
from /Users/alightholder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rspec-core-3.1.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `block in load_spec_files'
from /Users/alightholder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rspec-core-3.1.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `each'
from /Users/alightholder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rspec-core-3.1.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `load_spec_files'
from /Users/alightholder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rspec-core-3.1.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:96:in `setup'
from /Users/alightholder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rspec-core-3.1.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:84:in `run'
from /Users/alightholder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rspec-core-3.1.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
from /Users/alightholder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rspec-core-3.1.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:37:in `invoke'
from /Users/alightholder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rspec-core-3.1.2/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/alightholder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/rspec:19:in `load'
from /Users/alightholder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/rspec:19:in `<main>'
```

This looks like a configuration error to me. I've tried inserting /lib/ folder in between my idea_spec.rb and the /spec/ directory, but that didn't seem to help. I'm pretty sure I'm in the right folder and so far none of the guides on this site have been inaccurate or incomplete, so I'm at a loss why I'm getting a load error instead of a test run.

for "rspec spec/idea_spec.rb" I get:

```
/Users/alightholder/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- idea (LoadError)
from /Users/alightholder/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /Users/alightholder/Ruby/railsgirls_stuff/railsgirls/spec/idea_spec.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/alightholder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rspec-core-3.1.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `load'
from /Users/alightholder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rspec-core-3.1.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `block in load_spec_files'
from /Users/alightholder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rspec-core-3.1.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `each'
from /Users/alightholder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rspec-core-3.1.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `load_spec_files'
from /Users/alightholder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rspec-core-3.1.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:96:in `setup'
from /Users/alightholder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rspec-core-3.1.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:84:in `run'
from /Users/alightholder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rspec-core-3.1.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
from /Users/alightholder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rspec-core-3.1.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:37:in `invoke'
from /Users/alightholder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rspec-core-3.1.2/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/alightholder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/rspec:19:in `load'
from /Users/alightholder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/rspec:19:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

## Problem 1. idea_spec.rb (LoadError)

```
/Users/alightholder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rspec-core-3.1.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `load': cannot load such file -- /Users/alightholder/Ruby/railsgirls_stuff/railsgirls/spec/lib/idea_spec.rb (LoadError)
```

Try executing `rspec spec/idea_spec.rb`, i.e., don't include `lib`.

It looks like you've initialized rspec in a directory called `railsgirls` which should produce a subdirectory called `spec`. Once you create your `idea_spec.rb` within the `spec` directory, the path to that file should simply be `spec/idea_spec.rb` as opposed to `spec/lib/idea_spec.rb`. I can't tell why the author of that guide has included `lib`. Also, be sure to execute `rspec spec/idea_spec.rb` from your `railsgirls` directory.

## Problem 2. idea (LoadError)

```
/Users/alightholder/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- idea (LoadError)
```

Within `idea_spec.rb`, try changing

```
require "idea"
```

to

```
require "/Users/alightholder/Ruby/railsgirls_stuff/railsgirls/idea"
```

I'm assuming that your `idea.rb` is within your `railsgirls` directory -- if that's not right, replace the absolute path I used with the correct absolute path to your `idea.rb`.

After that, if you can run rspec without receiving a LoadError, then change from

```
require "/Users/alightholder/Ruby/railsgirls_stuff/railsgirls/idea"
```

(i.e., giving `require` an absolute path) to simply

```
require_relative "../idea"
```

Comment: This does not work but the error message changes slightly. Too long to paste here, see edit above.

Comment: That error message actually isn't a problem -- I mean, it's an error message, but you no longer have a problem with rspec. The problem now is that there is no `idea.rb` and the guide you linked to doesn't take you through the creation of such a file. In fact I think `idea.rb` is a kind of placeholder -- you can put anything you'd like in place of `idea.rb` -- it looks like the author didn't imagine that readers would _strictly_ follow their guide.

Comment: Oh... what directory is it in?